# Does anyone see where the graph disconnection is coming from?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am having the following error thrown, although I do not see where the disconnection is occuring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in getting the output of the layers from the base model, while nowhere in your model you use the input of the base model that generates those outputs.

> Problem here: `base_model.get_layer(concat_with).output`

The easiest solution for your case is to leave the normalization outsize the model, directly in the data or in the generator, and use:

```
img_input = base_model.input
encoded = base_model.output
```

This way you don't need to change `UpProject`. (This may still be problematic depending on whether the chosen layers were used more than once inside the base model)

Notice that if you want a pretrained base model to work correctly, you should use the correct preprocessing for this model:

```
keras.applications.densenet import preprocess_input
processed_images = preprocess_input(batch_of_images)
```

This works if you load images with PIL or Keras standard generators. If you open with `cv2`, then you need to flip the channels first.

Comment: This is for another question where you should explain how you saved these weights and how you're loading them.

Comment: Both load images in the scale between 0 and 255, but while PIL (I think this is the internal keras loader too) reads images in RGB, cv2 reads them in BGR format. Of course that load and plot with cv2 will show no problem, but if you use the same plotter to plot from PIL and from cv2 you will see the difference. If you are training your own model, no problem, you just need to remember how to reproduce the same image loading later. If you're using pretrained, then you need to know which preprocessing they used for training.